# Why do my fields not populate with current value on JQGrid Inline Edit?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid throughout my application. On two screens with inline edit, everything works fine. If a field has a value, it puts that value into the textbox when it goes to edit mode.

On one grid, this is not happening, and all fields go to blank when edit mode is activated.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

The code is a bit much, so I'll only post if someone requests it. For now, does anyone have thoughts as to why it's happening? Thanks!

**EDIT - Code:**

**The defaults get called first, then Init at the bottom kicks off the rest. Let me know if more is needed.**

Here is my setDefaults call:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
            datatype: 'json',
            height: "100%",
            loadui: 'none',
            images: "/css/redmond/images/",
            jsonReader: {
                root: "Rows",
                page: "Page",
                total: "Total",
                records: "Records",
                repeatitems: false,
                userdata: "UserData",
                id: "Id"
            },
            mtype: 'GET',
            autowidth: true,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
            viewrecords: true,
            loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert('todo: implement error method - ' + error);
            },
            beforeRequest: function () {
                $("#load_grid").html('<h4 style="display: inline; position: relative; top: -10px; font-weight: bold">Loading...</h4>' + $(".loader").html());
                Common.Helpers.DisableControls();

                if (multi !== undefined && !multi)
                    $("#grid").setGridParam({ multiselect: true }).showCol('cb');
            },
            gridComplete: function () {
                if (!loadonce) {
                    multi = false;
                    Common.Grid.LoadNavBar();
                    Common.Grid.InitFilters();
                    $("th[id=grid_cb]")
                        .css("text-align", "center")
                        .css("position", "relative")
                        .css("left", "1px");
                }

                Common.Helpers.EnableControls();
            }
        });
```

Here is all the code called on the page in question:

```
DoubleClickRow: function (id) {
            if ($("#" + id).find("img[alt=loading]").length > 0)
                alert('Please wait until row is fully loaded before editing.');
            else {
                var grid = $("#grid");
                if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                    grid.saveRow(lastsel, true);
                    $("#grid").setSelection(id);
                    lastsel = id;
                    grid.editRow(id, true,
                        function (row) {
                            $("#" + row + "_StoreQty").select();
                        },
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        { "DetailId": $("#grid").getCell(id, "DetailId") },
                        function (row) { // on success
                            var rowId = row;
                            var row = $("#" + rowId);
                            var grid = $("#grid");
                            grid.setSelection(row.next().attr("id"));
                            row.next().focus();
                            Store.Cuts.Index.DoubleClickRow(row.next().attr("id"));
                        },
                        null,
                        null
                    );
                }
            }
        },
        setupGrid: function (grid, pager) {

            Common.Grid.GetColumnModel();

            grid.jqGrid({
                colNames: colNames,
                colModel: colModel,
                pager: pager,
                editurl: editurl,
                url: gridurl,
                pager: pager,
                height: 250,
                rowNum: 20,
                ondblClickRow: Store.Cuts.Index.DoubleClickRow,
                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                        grid.saveRow(lastsel, true);
                    }
                },
                loadComplete: function () {
                    if (!loadonce) {
                        loadonce = true;

                        var ddlVendors = $(".ddl-vendors");
                        $(vendors).each(function () {
                            ddlVendors.append('<option value="' + this.Vendor + '">' + this.Vendor + '-' + this.VendorName + '</option>');
                        });

                        $(".footer-row").show();
                    }

                    if (grid.getGridParam("reccount") === 0) {
                        $("#empty-grid-message").show();
                    } else {
                        $("#empty-grid-message").hide();
                    }

                    grid
                        .setLabel('VendorItem', '', 'right')
                        .setLabel('UPC_DISPLAY', '', 'right')
                        .setLabel('CasePack', '', 'right')
                        .setLabel('Retail', '', 'right')
                        .setLabel('Express', '', 'right')
                        .setLabel('InvQty', '', 'right')
                        .setLabel('Qty', '', 'right')
                        .setLabel('StoreQty', '', 'right');

                    grid.resetSelection();

                    var rows = grid.getRowData();

                    $(rows).each(function () {
                        $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: pricingurl,
                            data: "di_id=" + this["ItemId"],
                            success: function (result) {
                                try {
                                    $("." + result.Id + "_Retail").html("").html(result.Retail);
                                    $("." + result.Id + "_Sale").html("").html(result.SaleAmt);
                                    $("." + result.Id + "_Inventory").html("").html(result.InvQty);
                                }
                                catch (ex) {
                                    $(".ajax").html(result);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        Init: function () {
            $.when(Store.Cuts.Index.GetPageData())
            .then(function () {
                Store.Cuts.Index.setupGrid($("#grid"), $("#pager"));
                Common.Grid.InitGridEdit($("#grid"), Store.Cuts.Index.DoubleClickRow);

                $(".ddl-vendors").change(function () {
                    extendedSearch.push({ name: "Vendor", value: $(".ddl-vendors").val() });
                    Common.Grid.FilterGrid();
                });

                $("#filter-div-btn-clear").click(function () {
                    $(".ddl-vendors").val("-1")
                    extendedSearch.push({ name: "Vendor", value: "-1" });
                });
            });
        }
```

Here is my colModel:

```
[{"Id":0,"display_order":0,"header":"ItemId","name":"ItemId","index":"ItemId","width":1,"align":"Left","search":false,"editable":false,"hidden":true,"editurl":"","edittype":"text","editoptions":{"_value":" ","value":""},"surl":"","bytype":"text","bydescr":""},
{"Id":0,"display_order":0,"header":"DetailId","name":"DetailId","index":"DetailId","width":1,"align":"Left","search":false,"editable":true,"hidden":true,"editurl":"","edittype":"text","editoptions":{"_value":" ","value":""},"surl":"","bytype":"text","bydescr":""},
{"Id":0,"display_order":0,"header":"Ship Date","name":"ShipDateDisplay","index":"ShipDateDisplay","width":75,"align":"Left","search":true,"editable":false,"hidden":false,"editurl":"","edittype":"text","editoptions":{"_value":" ","value":""},"surl":"","bytype":"twodates","bydescr":""},
{"Id":0,"display_order":0,"header":"Item","name":"VendorItem","index":"VendorItem","width":50,"align":"Right","search":true,"editable":false,"hidden":false,"editurl":"","edittype":"text","editoptions":{"_value":" ","value":""},"surl":"","bytype":"text","bydescr":""},
{"Id":0,"display_order":0,"header":"UPC","name":"UPC_DISPLAY","index":"UPC_DISPLAY","width":130,"align":"Right","search":true,"editable":false,"hidden":false,"editurl":"","edittype":"text","editoptions":{"_value":" ","value":""},"surl":"","bytype":"text","bydescr":""},
{"Id":0,"display_order":0,"header":"Description","name":"ItemDescription","index":"ItemDescription","width":200,"align":"Left","search":true,"editable":false,"hidden":false,"editurl":"","edittype":"text","editoptions":{"_value":" ","value":""},"surl":"","bytype":"text","bydescr":""},
{"Id":0,"display_order":0,"header":"Pack","name":"CasePack","index":"CasePack","width":35,"align":"Right","search":false,"editable":false,"hidden":false,"editurl":"","edittype":"text","editoptions":{"_value":" ","value":""},"surl":"","bytype":"text","bydescr":""},
{"Id":0,"display_order":0,"header":"Ret","name":"Retail","index":"Retail","width":50,"align":"Right","search":false,"editable":false,"hidden":false,"editurl":"","edittype":"","editoptions":{"_value":" ","value":""},"surl":"","bytype":"text","bydescr":""},
{"Id":0,"display_order":0,"header":"Exp","name":"Express","index":"Express","width":50,"align":"Right","search":false,"editable":false,"hidden":false,"editurl":"","edittype":"","editoptions":{"_value":" ","value":""},"surl":"","bytype":"text","bydescr":""},
{"Id":0,"display_order":0,"header":"Inv","name":"InvQty","index":"InvQty","width":30,"align":"Right","search":false,"editable":false,"hidden":false,"editurl":"","edittype":"","editoptions":{"_value":" ","value":""},"surl":"","bytype":"text","bydescr":""},
{"Id":0,"display_order":0,"header":"Memo","name":"Memo","index":"Memo","width":50,"align":"Left","search":false,"editable":false,"hidden":false,"editurl":"","edittype":"","editoptions":{"_value":" ","value":""},"surl":"","bytype":"text","bydescr":""},
{"Id":0,"display_order":0,"header":"Distro","name":"Qty","index":"Qty","width":50,"align":"Right","search":false,"editable":false,"hidden":false,"editurl":"","edittype":"","editoptions":{"_value":" ","value":""},"surl":"","bytype":"text","bydescr":""},
{"Id":0,"display_order":0,"header":"Request","name":"StoreQty","index":"StoreQty","width":60,"align":"Right","search":false,"editable":true,"hidden":false,"editurl":"","edittype":"text","editoptions":{"_value":" ","value":""},"surl":"","bytype":"text","bydescr":""},
{"Id":0,"display_order":0,"header":"Reason","name":"StoreReason","index":"StoreReason","width":160,"align":"Left","search":false,"editable":true,"hidden":false,"editurl":"","edittype":"select","editoptions":{"_value":"reasons ","value":"1:No Display/Running;0:Overstock"},"surl":"","bytype":"text","bydescr":""}]
```

Comment: I am afraid that without having at least the JavaScript code your problem can't be solved.

Comment: @Oleg - Ok...I'll try and get it all together.

Comment: Sorry, but the code which you posted don't contain enough information. In your code I could find `colModel: colModel` which gives absolutely no information without an example of `colModel`. On the other side the code contain `$("#" + row + "_StoreQty").select();`, `$("#grid").getCell(id, "DetailId")` and so on which get/change data from the corresponding grid column. How the columns are defined? Which data you use to fill the grid?

Comment: Moreover your code contain parts like `images: "/css/redmond/images/"` or you use `if (!loadonce) {...` in both `loadComplete` and `gridComplete`. Which version of jqGrid you use? The `image` parameter not exist in jqGrid since version 3.5. Do you use jqGrid 3.4 or some another retro versions? Since version 3.7 jqGrid support `loadonce` parameter do you not use it and simulate this yourself? How you see there are still too many opened questions.

Comment: @Oleg, sorry for the issues here. This is my first major project that I am incorporating jqGrid into. I've added the column model that I retrieve dynamically. Yes, there are extra fields in there due to the server side object I use to populate it. I will remove images as I did not know it was obsolete. The select() call is just used to highlight the first field for editing on edit. The getCell call is because I need that id to be posted on edit. the loadonce bit is my own variable to ensure certain things only happen on first load of grid (external filters, etc).

Comment: I will look at the new loadonce feature and see if it fits my needs. Hope this information helps. Thanks for taking the time to look through the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out.

In my server side object for colModel, if the editoptions was blank, I would send down the following:

```
editoptions":{"_value":" ","value":""}
```

This would cause it to be a blank value when edit mode was invoked. To solve this, I send back null instead of blank, and if the editoptions is null, I remove it completely from the colModel object.

```
$(colModel).each(function () {
      if (this.editoptions === null)
          delete this.editoptions;
});
```